# Backbone Forms - render options through array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

hello i want to create a edit interface for array based div-array.
for example i create in a loop 15 divs,

based on this i want to load via ajax an edit interface where i can
select one of those divs and change their classes,
like so, i can do this by hand,

```
 var divs = {
        'selector': ['Select One'],
        'id': ['div-1', 'div-2', 'div-3', 'div-4'],
        'class': ['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3', 'class-4']
    };
```

the point is i dont know how many they are until the user inputs a int to render them.
id and class should be populated based on my current rendered div amount,
for example:

current code:

```
   (function($) {
    var container = $('.holder');

    //The input getter for amount of divs
    var form1 = new Backbone.Form({
        schema: {
            nDefine: 'Number',
        }
    }).render();
    $('.input').append(form1.el);

// rendering amount of divs
function render(){
    num = parseInt($('input').val());
    for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         container.append('<div id="id'+i+'" class="box category'+i+'">Id:'+i+'</div>');

     }
}

// renders divs on click
$('.n-definer').click(function() {

    container.empty();
    render();
    //form1.commit();
});

})(jQuery);
```

this works fine,
    how can i get now those id's and classes into my backbone form selects in array form?

Comment: I've reread your question a few times and still unclear on what you're trying to do. I understand rendering the elements dynamically based on the JSON and giving them an `id` of div-1, etc. What do you mean by, getting those id`s and classes into my backbone form selects? Or you mean you want to do a `this.el.append(newElement);`?

Comment: after rendering and creating those id's and classes, i would like to be able to select one of them in a selectbox to add to an id another rendered and existing class, if my id's are cars, i would like to change their colours with those select options, => = id5 - has shipped by house class 5, i want to select in the select box id5 and change its class to 7

Comment: maybe i should populate those selects without backbone-forms for the first run

Comment: You don't really need `Backbone` for what you're trying to do. This is more towards building UI elements. Once you have coded that pseudocode, we can get back into turning it into a `Backbone` app.

Comment: ok thank you so far, gonna comment again when the code is there

Comment: here is the working app: https://github.com/marcheidemann/categoryDropChange